# Eclipse - Select Preferred Launcher

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, launcher

I am starting to learn C and am using Eclipse. When I first tried to debug (Run -> Debug As -> 1 Local C/C++ Application), this window popped:
[image: Select Preferred Launcher]

I suppose I have to check the "Use configuration specific settings", and by that enable the list of Launchers, but **which one of them should I choose?**

While searching for a similiar question I have encountered an answer stating choosing "Standard Create Process Launcher", however it was among many other steps, in order to solve a different problem. Hence I am not sure that this is what I should choose as well.

Thanks in advance,
Lee

Comment: Have you ***[looked at this?](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Frun-debug%2Fref-default_launchers.htm)***  Evidently, you have multiple launchers installed, and it is just asking which one you want to use...  _For the most part, this page remains disabled, as concurrent overlapping tooling is very rare, but in the event there is overlap_.  So what tools are you building with, and what makes sense.  Don't avoid experimentation with each to see which one does what you want.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at this, but it is not the same situation. Meanwhile I have chosen the Standard laucher, and it seems to be OK. Thank you.